# issue in deleting when we have more than 1 file

Tags: asp.net

i have  10  files. i want to delete them but the  condition here is
  as  i delete file  1 to  file 5 .let say in  file6  i  got an  exception then in that case  i should  restore all the  files  deleted

i should delete the  files only if there is no exception occured in  any of the file when we try to  delete

something  like rollback transcation what we  do in DB.  is there any properties in file  we  can achive this  concept

anyhelp  would be great thank  you

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in two phases. First, rename all the files (or more them). Then, once you're happy that all the files are deletable you can go and really delete them. If not, then you rename them back (or move them back) to their original state.

The actual deletion could happen as a batch job as well.

Comment: The only problem with this is you can rename a file that is in use. If you were to do this then it would still fail to delete the file when you came to do your second pass.

Comment: True. In which case you could either move them before deleting, or use copy the files delete the originals, rollback using the copies if required and delete the copies if all goes well.

If you add this functionality then you're pretty much at the point where you can offer an "undo" feature for situations where these files get deleted by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If transactional NTFS doesn't work out for you, you could take the route of copying all the files to a temp location before deleting... then catch any exceptions. If there are exceptions, check to see if each file exists, and if not just copy back any that are missing from the temp location.

If the files don't tend to be too large, you could also consider storing the files in a relational database where you get that kind of transactional support and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Transactional NTFS which does what you want it to. I've not tried it myself but here is a link to use it in .net

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/txfmanaged